# QT window not accessing another class object

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to make a File Management System. I am new to QT and cannot understand what could be causing this problem. Any help would be appreciated.
I have a FileSystem class that i want to use in window2 (window2 is actually my main window)

```
//These are just some of methods of my FileSystem class

//Check if Folder exists
bool FileSystem:: folderExists(const Folder * pointerToCurrentFolder, string folderName) {
    //code if folder exists or not
}

//Create Folder
void FileSystem::createFolder(Folder * pointerToParentFolder, string fName) {
    //code to create a folder
}
```

I have a window2 class and i use the instance of FileSystem in window2. I also include FileSystem header class in window2.

```
private:
    FileSystem fs;

public:
    void setFileSystem(FileSystem f){
        fs=f;
    }
    FileSystem getFileSystem(){
        return fs;
    }
```

I want to use this fs instance in 3rd window (name: MainWindow) by using window2

```
private:
    window2* w2;
public:
    void setWindow2(window2* wt){
        w2=wt;
    }
    window2* getWindow2(){
        return w2;
    }
```

I try to access the fs object created in window2 in MainWindow like this:

```
void MainWindow::on_createAFolderBt_clicked() //create a folder command
{
    bool ok;
    QString fname=QInputDialog::getText(this,"File Management System", "Type name of Folder",QLineEdit::Normal, QDir::home().dirName(),&ok);
    string newfolderName= fname.toLocal8Bit().constData(); //convert QString to std::string
if (ok){
    if (w2->getFileSystem().folderExists(w2->getFileSystem().navigator,newfolderName)){
        QMessageBox::warning(this,"","This Folder already exists");
    }
}
```

Whenever i press ok of the input dialogue box, my application stops working and when i debug it, it shows the error in stl::vector of c++ of 'Read Access Violation'. I use vectors multiple times in my code of FileSystem. Is it because filesystem object gets destroyed when the window closes?

Comment: ***it shows the error in vector class of c++.*** which vector class????

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ stl::vector of c++

Comment: Where do you initialize `MainWindow::w2`?  Are you sure it points to a valid `window2` instance at the point at which it's used?

Comment: @G.M. I did w2=new window2(); in MainClass method where it is used after your comment, the problem doesn't go away

Comment: In that case my guess would be that you have undefined behaviour somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as per My understanding you are trying to create an object of FileSystem which is defined in mainwindow and when it goes out of scope it gets destroyed but if you want it `FileSystem` across you application you can make it a singleton class.

Secondly you are using std string and vector it will dispatch the container every time it allocates the memory you need to use qt containers they are way more fast and optimized for qt framework.

Give it a try and it will fix your problem.